# NGINX: too many redirects

Tags: nginx

I'm hosting a meteor app behind an nginx proxy. We were using https (and thus 301 redirecting all http connections to 443). However, we've now gone back to http (and thus 301 redirecting all https connections to 80).

When I try to visit my site, I get an error saying, "The page isn’t redirecting properly". However, if I visit in incognito or after clearing my browser cache and cookies, everything works again.

Can I change anything in my nginx conf file (below) to fix this? I really don't want all of my visitors to have to clear their browsing data. Thanks!

```
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

# this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP
server {    
    listen 80;
    server_name [REDACTED];

   # redirect to meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP
    }

}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
    server_name [REDACTED];
    root html; # irrelevant
    index index.html; # irrelevant

    # redirect to http
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/[REDACTED].pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/[REDACTED].pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers '[REDACTED]'
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    # If your application is not compatible with IE <= 10, this will redirect visitors to a page advising a browser update
    # This works because IE 11 does not present itself as MSIE anymore
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE" ) {
        return 303 https://browser-update.org/update.html;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
       allow all;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have problems - your Strict-Transport-Security header prevents your previous visitors from accessing your site over `http`.

Comment: @RichardSmith - thx so much. Is there a way for me to remove that header from my previous visitors?

Comment: @RichardSmith, woot! Fixed it, thanks! If you submit as an answer, I'll be sure to accept. To fix, I did two things: 1) I removed the line `add_header Strict-Transport-Security...` and 2) I added `proxy_hide_header Strict-Transport-Security;` to both http and http locations `location / {`